# LEFT JOIN condition not respected in COUNT(*)

Tags: mysql, sql

I will describe (hopefully all) important bits:

I have a table `sup_tickets` which holds all ticket and these `tickets` can be labelled. Relation is `M:N` and middle table is `sup_labels2tickets`.

I want to get count of all the tickets in the table `sup_tickets` for each corresponding `label` if there are no labels for a ticket show 0. Do not omit the output as show on second image.

Labels are also assigned to specific queues, and tickets are also assigned to specific queues, but it sometimes happens that ticket is in a label that is not in a same queue as ticket itself.

I came up with this two queries, the problem in 1st query is that `2nd LEFT JOIN` does not respect `t.queue_id = @queue_id` and it returns inaccurate result if ticket is in different queue than corresponding label is.

The first one almost works:

```
SELECT COUNT(l2t.id) AS `count`, l.name, l.id, l.priority FROM sup_labels AS l
LEFT JOIN sup_labels2tickets AS l2t ON l.id = l2t.label_id
LEFT JOIN sup_tickets as t ON t.id = l2t.ticket_id AND t.queue_id = @queue_id AND t.state = @state
WHERE l.queue_id = @queue_id
GROUP BY l.id
```

it produces this result:

[image: Resultset 1]

But if I move the `t.queue_id = @queue_id` out to a WHERE statement it omits the labels with 0 count.

```
SELECT COUNT(l2t.id) AS `count`, l.name, l.id, l.priority FROM sup_labels AS l
LEFT JOIN sup_labels2tickets AS l2t ON l.id = l2t.label_id
LEFT JOIN sup_tickets as t ON t.id = l2t.ticket_id AND t.state = @state
WHERE l.queue_id = @queue_id AND t.queue_id = @queue_id
GROUP BY l.id
```

[image: Resultset 2]

Any idea what could it be or how should I do this correctly?

ps. I just noticed that t.state is also not respected towards `count(*)`

Comment: moving `AND t.queue_id = @queue_id` from the `ON` condition to the `WHERE` clause effectively changes the `LEFT JOIN` to a plain `JOIN` (since it forces `t.queue_id` to be NOT NULL)

Comment: @joop I don't know if its relevant, but all of the `tickets` have queue_id set (not null)

Comment: Except the records with `l2t.ticket_id` = 33 or 34; these don't exist at all in table `sup_tickets`.

Comment: @joop that is true, what do you suggest. I can't see the answer clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `SELECT COUNT(l2t.id)` to `SELECT COUNT(t.id)` in the first query - if you want to see the number of records successfully returned from an outer joined table, you need to query a (non-null) data item *from that table*.

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
SELECT COUNT(t.id) AS `count`, l.name, l.id FROM sup_labels AS l
LEFT JOIN sup_labels2tickets AS l2t ON l.id = l2t.label_id
LEFT JOIN sup_tickets as t ON t.id = l2t.ticket_id AND t.queue_id = @queue_id  AND t.state = @state
where l.queue_id = @queue_id
GROUP BY l.id
```

Working fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e210ae/2